# border-spacing css property overrides table cellspacing

Tags: css, css-tables, cellspacing, border-spacing

I use wysiwyg editor. If I insert table and set Cell Spacing to 30, it won't make any affect because border-spacing is set to 0 in main css file to which I don't have access.

I can override border-spacing with inline style, but I don't know what Cell Spacing will be selected in user side so I can not just set border-spacing to the same number because I don't know this number.

Is there any way to delete border-spacing value or is any other solution to this problem? Too bad there is no "none" value for border-spacing property.

Comment: What “user side” are you referring to?

Comment: Any user who uses editor inside my Magento extension.